# Android Realtime Multiplayer (GPGS): Not receiving packets after reconnect via in-game invitation

Tags: java, android, networking, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have a game which uses GPGS Realtime Multiplayer on Android. Everything works fine when I don't use the in-game notification for invites. If I use it, it works only the first time after the game is launched. Afterwards, a player is able to reconnect, but the host does not receive the packets which are being sent from the other client. The other client does receive packets which are being sent from the host.

I keep thinking that the other client must be sending packets to the previous room or something. If I log the packets being sent, I can see that they are being sent, but the host does not receive any packet from `onRealTimeMessageReceived()`.

If I restart the other client, and keep the host running, it will work. But if I restart the host and keep the other client running, it will not work. The issue must be on the other client.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out I was setting the Room ID variable only when it was equal to `null`. Which means that it was only setting it one time, and still sending the messages to the previous Room ID.